# Why wont the contents of <ul> appear?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Im trying to learn pagination , but i don't know why the contents of "li" under the "ul" disappear and why the "ul" container still continues to appear even tough i stated in the js that only 6 should be only visible in the page.
btw the "ul" and "li" is under a while loop in php.

is it because of my design or my HTML structure? how i input things into js? or on how i created the whole thing?
[image: result]
[image: resultnotblack]

thanks in advance

```js
pageSize = 6;

$(function() {
  var pageCount = Math.ceil($(".job").size() / pageSize);

  for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
    if (i == 0)
      $("#pagination").append('<li><a class="current" href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>');
    else
      $("#pagination").append('<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>');
  }


  showPage(1);

  $("#pagination li a").click(function() {
    $("#pagination li a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
  });

})

showPage = function(page) {
  $(".job").hide();

  $(".job").job(function(n) {
    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
      $(this).show();
  });
}
```

```css
.job-list-container {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 85%;
  height: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: 55%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* display of flex */

.single-job-container {
  margin-top: .7%;
  margin-bottom: .8%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 45%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background-color: black;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.job p {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.job {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.job .trabaho {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}


/* javascipt pagination */

.current {
  color: green;
}

#pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```
    <section class='jobs-container'> 
     <ul id="pagination"></ul>
            <div class='job-list-container'>

                    <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM available_jobs";
                        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
                        $pre = $row['Prefecture'];
                        $city = $row['City']; 
                        $company = $row['Company'];
                        $job= $row['JobName'];
                        $salary =$row['Salary'];
                        $time =$row['WorkTime']; ?>
                        <ul class="single-job-container">
                            <li class='job'>
                            <p>Time: <?php echo $time ?></p>
                            <p class='trabaho'> <?php echo $job ?></p> 
                            <p>Prefecture: <?php echo $pre ?> </p>
                            <p>City: <?php echo $city ?> </p> 
                            <p>Company: <?php echo $company?> </p>  
                            <p>Salary: <?php echo $salary ?> </p> 

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>


            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but pagination logic should be in PHP. Instead of getting all the entries, get 20 and total count and depending on total count value, display pages.

Comment: @Ravenous , thanks for the reply, but with fetch_assoc, can you actually limit the number of entries to some degree?

Comment: Your `ul` are never hidden; only the `li` inside them. `$(".job").job` is not a jQuery method. Should be `$(".job").each`. If you would have looked at the console, you would have been informed about this error.

Comment: You have to use MySQL `LIMIT`, selecting * from a table with thousands/millions of entries like that will just be a performance killer. Read this -
 https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928

Comment: @Ravenous thanks for the link man, ill look into it.

Comment: @trincot thanks for the reply, by having only the Mli> hidden you mean the $(".job").hide ? should i put the whole container into the method?

Comment: If your intention is to hide the `ul` then your selector should not be `.job` (which are `li` elements), but `.single-job-container` (which are `ul` elements).

Answer (score 0):

i got it thanks !

```js
pageSize = 6;

$(function() {
  var pageCount = Math.ceil($(".single-job-container").size() / pageSize);

  for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
    if (i == 0)
      $("#pagination").append('<li><a class="current" href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>');
    else
      $("#pagination").append('<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>');
  }


  showPage(1);

  $("#pagination li a").click(function() {
    $("#pagination li a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
  });

})

showPage = function(page) {
  $(".single-job-container").hide();

  $(".single-job-container").each(function(n) {
    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
      $(this).show();
  });
}
```

but if $('job').each isnt a JQuery then why does this runs?

```js
//Pagination
pageSize = 8;

$(function() {
  var pageCount = Math.ceil($(".line-content").size() / pageSize);

  for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
    if (i == 0)
      $("#pagin").append('<li><a class="current" href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>');
    else
      $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>');
  }


  showPage(1);

  $("#pagin li a").click(function() {
    $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
  });

})

showPage = function(page) {
  $(".line-content").hide();

  $(".line-content").each(function(n) {
    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
      $(this).show();
  });
}
```

```css
.current {
  color: green;
}

#pagin li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="trial.css">
  <script src="trial.js"></script>


 </head>
 <body>
 <ul>  
<li class="line-content">1 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">2 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">3 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">4 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">5 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">6 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">7 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">8 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">9 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">10 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">11 I have some content</li>
<li class="line-content">12 I have some content</li>
</ul>

<ul id="pagin">
         
</ul>


 </body>
</html>
```

is the .job a reserved word?